# http://104.225.171.33/

Tags: google-chrome, url

Why did all my tabs suddenly reload and go to a new website with the URL http://104.225.171.33/, which does not load? I'm on Google Chrome. After I go type in the URL on those pages, though, it works all fine.

Comment: Not an answer, but this sounds like an issue with whomever designed/is hosting the web site, rather than Chrome.

Comment: It might be also malware/virus. Please add some more info and adjust the title to not contain an URL only. Were different websites open in the tabs that reloaded, or different pages on the same website/domain? Can it be replicated with this or other websites, or with a different browser? If you are able to narrow or down to a specific website on multiple browsers, you may contact their webmaster.